# Multiple pages WPF same components

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, frame

I created a Main window and 2 pages.

The pages has the same components as the main page but in different colors.

1) Is there a need to check the names of all the components so it will differ from the main?

- Since I had errors saying there is no definition for methods as .Close or `Dragmove` I removed it from the `Optimizer.xaml`

2) The page wont change:

```
private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Main.Content = new Optimizer();
....}
```

The Page design (Same as main just changed color to check):

```
<Page x:Class="Tool.Optimizer"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tool"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="637" d:DesignWidth="975.5"
      Title="Optimizer">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Opacity="0.6"/>
        <Image Margin="155,0,0,0" Source="Background.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0.8"/>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="235" Background="#FFF30909" Opacity="1
              ">
            <Button x:Name="Search" Content="&#xE71E;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="184,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="47" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="16"/>
        </Grid>
        <Image Source="Icon.ico" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.52,0.125" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="229" Height="132" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="6,0,0,0"/>
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,597">
            <Button x:Name="Close" Content="&#xEF2C;" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="40" Margin="0,0,1,0">
                <Button.BorderBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF2C46BB" Opacity="0"/>
                </Button.BorderBrush>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="Maximize" Content="&#xEF2E;" Height="40" Margin="0,0,41,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="40" >
                <Button.BorderBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF2C46BB" Opacity="0"/>
                </Button.BorderBrush>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="Minimize" Content="&#xEF2D;" Margin="0,0,81,0" Background="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="40" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Button.BorderBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0"/>
                </Button.BorderBrush>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="Username" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="16,252,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="120" Margin="16,132,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225" FontSize="20"><Run Text="Welcome to Osrs Tool!"/><LineBreak/><Run/><LineBreak/><Run Text="Please Enter your Username:"/><LineBreak/><Run/></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Main XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="GUI" x:Class="Tool.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tool"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="637" Width="975.5" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
    <Window.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.2"/>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown">
        <Frame x:Name = "Main"/>
        <Grid Opacity="0.6"/>
        <Image Margin="155,0,0,0" Source="Background.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0.8"/>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="235" Background="White" Opacity="1
              ">
            <Button x:Name="Search" Content="&#xE71E;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="184,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="47" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Background="{x:Null}" Click="Search_Click" FontSize="16"/>
        </Grid>
        <Image Source="Icon.ico" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.52,0.125" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="229" Height="132" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="6,0,0,0"/>
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,597">
            <Button x:Name="Close" Content="&#xEF2C;" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Foreground="White" Click="Close_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="40" Margin="0,0,1,0">
                <Button.BorderBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF2C46BB" Opacity="0"/>
                </Button.BorderBrush>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="Maximize" Content="&#xEF2E;" Height="40" Margin="0,0,41,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" Click="Maximize_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="40" >
                <Button.BorderBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF2C46BB" Opacity="0"/>
                </Button.BorderBrush>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="Minimize" Content="&#xEF2D;" Margin="0,0,81,0" Background="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="40" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Minimize_Click">
                <Button.BorderBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0"/>
                </Button.BorderBrush>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="Username" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="16,252,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="120" Margin="16,132,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225" FontSize="20"><Run Text="Welcome to Osrs Tool!"/><LineBreak/><Run/><LineBreak/><Run Text="Please Enter your Username:"/><LineBreak/><Run/></TextBlock>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: WPF/UWP and XAML are designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. While you can use other patterns doing so misses about 90% of it's power and runs into issue at every other corner. Considering the amount of questions you ask/work you do regarding code behind, I highly doubt this is a proper MVVM pattern. If you plan on staying in WPF, you should definitely learn MVVM. I wrote a intro a few years back, should still get you onto the right track: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Answer (score 0):

No it's safe, the names are per page and of that type so it's just as safe as using the same name in multiple objects.

Comment: Im getting then alot of errors saying :'Optimizer' does not contain a definition for.... and it goes for all the components in the page.

Comment: Try ```Main.Navigate(new Optimizer());```

Comment: Post the entire view for Window and Page and if you've done any code behind post that also please.

Comment: Works however it seems like the frame appears above the main window and not instead so now I have 2 frames on my window.

Comment: You're frame is behind everything else on your Window in the Grid. I'm not sure what you're saying about two frames but you have your Window visuals on top of your Frame yes.